# How to use hook_swiper_options_alter($node, $plugin_options) {} in Drupal-7

Tags: drupal-7, swiper.js

I have been searching for a few days to figure out how to change the options for the swiper (v 7.x-1.4) module in Drupal-7.  The documentation is clear-as-mud explaining how the module expects this hook to be used.  I'm looking for a simple code example on how to implement the following options from the swiper API:

```
autoplay
prevButton
nextButton
autoplayDisableOnInteraction
```

The only documentation reference I have been able to find is from the README.txt in the module:

```
...
You can also add, change and remove, any of API options of the Swipers, 
just you need to implement a hook:
hook_swiper_options_alter($node, $plugin_options) {}

This way the module will handle pass these options to the script that 
instantiates the swiper Plugin.
...
```

I'm fairly new to Drupal, but I am trying to learn.  I have attempted to create a simple custom module to implement these options.  I have called my module myCustom, created the /drupal/sites/all/modules/myCustom directory with the following files:

myCustom.info:

```
name = myCustom
description = customize swiper
package = me
version = 0.02
core = 7.x

files[] = myCustom.module
```

myCustom.module:

```
<?php
function myCustom_swiper_options_alter($node, $plugin_options) 
{
  $plugin_options += (
    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
    paginationClickable: true,
    autoplay: 2500,
    autoplayDisableOnInteraction: true
  );
  return($node, $plugin_options);
}
```

I know I have multiple problems.  Drupal refuses to enable my module as-is and I can not figure out why.  I have checked the admin->reports->recent log messages  report and found nothing relevant to at least help me troubleshoot.

Any ideas how I can fix this?  Does anyone have a working example of code that I can copy and modify to get this hook working?

Thank you in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to read through this documentation: [Writing module .info files (Drupal 7.x)](https://www.drupal.org/node/542202#files).

- Remove this line from your `.info` file: `files[] = myCustom.module`. Drupal will automatically read through the `.module` file.
- As you defined a **version** in your `.info` file this may need your attention: [Release naming conventions](https://www.drupal.org/node/1015226), but actually you can just leave that out as well, it's not mandatory.
- Since you're using a hook from that swiper module, I recommend to set it as a dependency in your custom module's `.info` file as: `dependencies[] = swiper` to prevent unmet dependency errors.
- Change the `$plugin_options` array to a php array & do not return anything:

  ```
  <?php

  function YOUR_MODULE_swiper_options_alter($node, &$plugin_options) {

      $plugin_options += array( 
          'nextButton' => '.swiper-button-next',
          'prevButton' => '.swiper-button-prev',
          'paginationClickable' => true,
          'autoplay' => 2500,
          'autoplayDisableOnInteraction' => true,
      );

  }
  ```
- *Additionally:* Try to refrain from using capitals in module names as per **machine name** (module dir name). If you take a look at other Drupal modules in `/modules` or `sites/all/modules` they're all lowercased. (You can leave the name in your `.info` file which also represents your module in the **modules list** as you have now.)

Comment: Success!  Thank you BaikHo!  The module is now functional and autoplay is now working.  The prev/next buttons do not work yet, but at least I know my options are being read by the swiper module.  Now I can figure out what options I want to utilize from the API.